# Does ROS2 support python 3.11?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys!
I want to know whether ROS2 supports python 3.11, currently?

Your answer and guide will be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417325/does-ros2-support-python-3.11?/) by [songyuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/53946/songyuc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2023-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Officially? No.

Iron requires Python `3.8.2` at a minimum (on Windows), and various versions of Python 3 on other platforms.

The newest would be `3.10.8` on macOS, but on Ubuntu (`jammy`), it standardised on `3.10.6`.

This means that the Ubuntu binary packages (which is what most ROS users will be using to install ROS 2 Iron) will only be built for Python `3.10.6`. Note that some of the core ROS 2 Python packages (such as `rclpy`) are mixed Python & C/C++, so using a different interpreter is not always just a matter of updating the path to the `python` binary.

See [REP 2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms: Iron Irwini (May 2023 - November 2024)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#iron-irwini-may-2023-november-2024) for all the details.

Note: you *may* be able to build ROS 2 Iron from source for your desired Python 3 version, but no one can guarantee you it will work, and it would not be officially supported.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [songyuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/53946/songyuc/) on 2023-07-10**:
Thank you sincerely for your guide!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-07-11**:
Could you please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer if you feel it has been answered? Thanks.

**Comment by [songyuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/53946/songyuc/) on 2023-07-12**:
OK, I did it.

**Comment by [songyuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/53946/songyuc/) on 2023-07-12**:
Hi! Is there any official plan of newest ROS2 like Ridley, for the support on Win11?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-07-12**:
Not that I know of, but I would not be the person in charge of that.

You'd want to ask the main ROS 2 developers.

**Comment by [songyuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/53946/songyuc/) on 2023-07-12**:
Got it, and thanks again.